# Android Camera2 onCaptureStarted Callback

Tags: android, android-camera2

I want to get signal in the start of the exposure.

I found in [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.html#onCaptureStarted(android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession,%20android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20long,%20long)) the callback:
**onCaptureStarted**

> This method is called when the camera device has started capturing the output image for the request, at the beginning of image exposure, or when the camera device has started processing an input image for a reprocess request.
>
> For a regular capture request, this callback is invoked right as the capture of a frame begins, so it is the most appropriate time for playing a shutter sound, or triggering UI indicators of capture.

I used it and get this results:

1. **~0.2ms** exposure (ACAMERA_SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME: 170980)
   A) The diff between the image timestamp to the current onCaptureStarted timestamp is: **37.488015** ms.
   B) The diff between onCaptureStarted to CameraImageReader::ImageCallback is: **9.630366**
2. **~5ms** exposure (ACAMERA_SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME: 4958439)
   A) The diff between the image timestamp to the current onCaptureStarted timestamp is: **42.577876** ms.
   B) The diff between onCaptureStarted to CameraImageReader::ImageCallback is: **9.839168**
3. **~20ms** exposure (ACAMERA_SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME: 19961992)
   A) The diff between the image timestamp to the current onCaptureStarted timestamp is: **58.494590** ms.
   B) The diff between onCaptureStarted to CameraImageReader::ImageCallback is: **9.060730**

NOTES
1. I tested with Pixel2 (manual exposure + 33ms frame duration)
2. I tested it also with 'TEMPLATE_MANUAL' and get same results.
3. I tested also with S9+ and get same results.
4. The numbers is not accurate.

---

It's seems that I get the callback after the exposure finished. like the second option in the doc:

> or when the camera device has started processing an input image for a reprocess request.

But I want to get it like the first option:

> at the beginning of image exposure

1) Can I control it?
2) What is "regular capture request"?
[NOTE: I used the 'ACameraCaptureSession_setRepeatingRequest']

Comment: How are you matching up the onCaptureStarted callbacks and the ImageReader images?  If you're repeating the capture request, there will be an offset between when they're invoked, so you may be comparing a later onCaptureStarted with an earlier Image.  I would try a single capture so it's easy to tell that you have the same image/capturestarted pair.

Comment: You ask about: 'The diff between onCaptureStarted to onCaptureCompleted...'? the "image timestamp" is same in the both callback. what I checked is the time that take between them.

Comment: @EddyTalvala - sorry but I wrong in one thing. "The diff between onCaptureStarted to onCaptureCompleted" is need to be "The diff between onCaptureStarted to CameraImageReader::ImageCallback". I edited it. thanks

Comment: NOTE: I use 'AImageReader_acquireLatestImage(m_pReader, &image)' to get the image.

Answer (score 1):

onCaptureStarted will happen quite a bit before the image is available to the application. At full resolution, it takes Pixel 2 ~33 ms to read out the image frame after exposure completes, plus some time to finish processing the buffer into YUV.

So if you see the Image available callback roughly 33 ms + exposure time later from the onCaptureStarted timestamp, that's expected. In your case:

- 0.2 ms exposure: 37.488015 ms - 170980 ns = 37.3 ms for readout + processing
- 5 ms exposure: 42.577876 ms - 4958439 ns = 37.6 ms for readout + processing
- 20 ms exposure: 58.494590 ms - 19961992 ns = 38.53 ms for readout + processing

That seems pretty much as expected, about 33 ms for readout +  5 ms for finishing processing.

Comment: This roughly what I thought (and write - 'It's seems that I get the callback after the exposure finished'). but this don't answer on my question. 'I want to get signal in the start of the exposure. ... But I want to get it like the first option: at the beginning of image exposure 1) Can I control it? 2) What is "regular capture request"?' thanks!

Comment: Another thing: ' it takes Pixel 2 ~33 ms to read out the image frame' - the readout + exposure can take more then the frame duration?

Comment: You mean that to the Pixel 2 sensor have buffer for the readout?

Comment: The image capture hardware is a pipeline with multiple stages.  It can be exposing frame N while reading out frame N+1, and doing final post-processing on frame N+2.  There is no guarantee about the latency between start of exposure and when the buffer becomes available to you, though most devices try to keep it short to minimize preview lag (how far back in time is what the preview shows).  For JPEG captures in particular the compression can take quite a while.

Comment: OK. but again 'I want to get signal in the start of the exposure..' - can I get it?

Comment: That's what onCaptureStarted is.

Comment: As I already wrote the timestamp of the image and my timestamp of the onCaptureStarted is differet... "It's seems that I get the callback after the exposure finished. like the second option in the doc:"